# How to change the border color (or remove the border) of a PropertyGrid control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

Having a standard WinForms 2.0 [`PropertyGrid` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) I'm looking for a way to either change the border color of the control or remove the border altogether.

[image]

I'm aware of the [`LineColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.linecolor.aspx) which unfortunately only changes the inner borders between the cells.

Additionally, I used [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net) to take a look at the source code of the `PropertyGrid` control and still found nothing meaningful to me.

**My question is:**

How to remove the outer border of a `PropertyGrid` control or change the color of the outer border?

**Update 2012-05-04 - Solution (aka "hack"):**

Based on [Jamie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10445278/107625) I assembled a working solution ([which you can download from here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/Uploads/235/TestBorderlessPropertyGrid.zip)):

[image]

The idea is to place the property grid inside a panel and let the panel clip the control.

With this approach, I did place the clipping panel into another panel that has a `Padding` of "1" (or whatever you want the borders to be) and gave this panel a `BackColor` that serves as the border color (green in my example).

Set the Anchor of the property grid to "Left, Right, Top, Bottom", set the `Dock` of the clipping panel to "Full".

[image]

This works well for my requirements. I would see this as kind of a hack since it consumes the resources of two panels which I hoped I could save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is another alternative, as it seems that my first answer is not suitable for this particular control. This is a dirty trick but should work:

Put a Panel control in your window or dialog, let say with size 100H x 300V. Put the propertygrid inside the panel with position -1,-1 and size 102,302.

Comment: Hehe, I already tried that in the past, unsuccessfully. I'll try it again once more, just in case I did something wrong.

Comment: @Jamie It worked, thanks for your suggestion! I'll update my question with your answer.

Comment: Be careful, this one can byte when the windows are resized because of automatic form scaling.  You really want to write code in the panel's Resize event handler to always make sure the PropertyGrid is where it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code from my project

PropertyGrid have two controls that need process. 

+ doccomment is Document help.

+ gridView that display property value.

Those controls draw border rectangle with color ControlDark.

We need re draw rectangle with HelpBackColor and LineColor to make clear view.

```
    namespace Bravo.Bravo7.UI
    {
        public class MyPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid
        {
            public class SnappableControl : NativeWindow
            {
                private Control _parent;
                private MyPropertyGrid _ownerGrid;

                public SnappableControl(Control parent, MyPropertyGrid ownerGrid)
                {
                    _parent = parent;
                    _parent.HandleCreated += _parent_HandleCreated;
                    _parent.HandleDestroyed += _owner_HandleDestroyed;

                    _ownerGrid = ownerGrid;
                }

                protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
                {
                    base.WndProc(ref m);

                    switch (m.Msg)
                    {
                        case (int)NativeMethods.WM_NCPAINT:
                        case (int)NativeMethods.WM_PAINT:

                            using (var g = _parent.CreateGraphics())
                            {
                                using (var pen = new Pen(_ownerGrid.HelpBackColor))
                                {
                                    var clientRectangle = _parent.ClientRectangle;
                                    clientRectangle.Width--;
                                    clientRectangle.Height--;
                                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, clientRectangle);
                                }
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                }

                void _owner_HandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    ReleaseHandle();
                }

                void _parent_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    AssignHandle(_parent.Handle);
                }
            }

            public class PropertyGridView : NativeWindow
            {
                private Control _parent;
                private MyPropertyGrid _ownerGrid;

                public PropertyGridView(Control parent, MyPropertyGrid ownerGrid)
                {
                    _parent = parent;
                    _parent.HandleCreated += _owner_HandleCreated;
                    _parent.HandleDestroyed += _owner_HandleDestroyed;

                    _ownerGrid = ownerGrid;
                }

                protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
                {
                    base.WndProc(ref m);

                    switch (m.Msg)
                    {
                        case (int)NativeMethods.WM_NCPAINT:
                        case (int)NativeMethods.WM_PAINT:

                            using (var g = _parent.CreateGraphics())
                            {
                                using (var pen = new Pen(_ownerGrid.LineColor))
                                {
                                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, _parent.Width - 1, _parent.Height - 1);
                                }
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                }

                void _owner_HandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    ReleaseHandle();
                }

                void _owner_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    AssignHandle(_parent.Handle);
                }
            }

            public class MyToolStripRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
            {
                protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
                {
                    //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
                }
            }

            public MyPropertyGrid()
            {
                base.LineColor = SystemColors.Control;
                base.ViewBackColor = Color.FromArgb(246, 246, 246);

                base.DrawFlatToolbar = true;
                base.ToolStripRenderer = new MyToolStripRenderer();

                var docDocument = typeof(PropertyGrid)
                    .GetField("doccomment", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetValue(this) as Control;

                new SnappableControl(docDocument, this);

                var gridView = typeof(PropertyGrid)
                    .GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetValue(this) as Control;

                new PropertyGridView(gridView, this);
            }

        }

    }
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Explain the context as well

Answer (score 1):

you will need a bit of interop for that:

```
[DllImport("User32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int Index, int Value);
[DllImport("User32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int Index);

int GWL_STYLE = -16;
int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
IntPtr hWnd = yourPropertyGrid.Handle;

int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style = style & ~WS_BORDER;
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

Comment: Thank, @Jamie I tried this, but unfortunately the style already seems to omit the style, thus removing it, does not change. Have you tried your solution and had it working?

Comment: Hi Uwe, no, I haven't tried, it is just the standard way to remove the border of a native windows control. it seems that the propertygrid is not following this standard, so, I think you won't be able to do it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

this code work.

```
private void SetHelpBoderColor(bool showBorder)
{
    if (showBorder)
    {
        //Set Default ViewBackColor
        PropertyInfo viewBackColor = this.propertyGrid.GetType().GetProperty("ViewBorderColor");
        if (viewBackColor != null)
            viewBackColor.SetValue(this.propertyGrid, SystemColors.ControlDark, null);

        //Set Default HelpBorderColor
        PropertyInfo helpBorderColor = this.propertyGrid.GetType().GetProperty("HelpBorderColor");
        if (helpBorderColor != null)
            helpBorderColor.SetValue(this.propertyGrid, SystemColors.ControlDark, null);

    }
    else
    {
        //Set ViewBackColor
        PropertyInfo viewBackColor = this.propertyGrid.GetType().GetProperty("ViewBorderColor");
        if (viewBackColor != null)
            viewBackColor.SetValue(this.propertyGrid, SystemColors.Control, null);

        //Set HelpBorderColor
        PropertyInfo helpBorderColor = this.propertyGrid.GetType().GetProperty("HelpBorderColor");
        if (helpBorderColor != null)
            helpBorderColor.SetValue(this.propertyGrid, SystemColors.Control, null);
    }

    if (DesignMode)
    {
        Parent.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that code can show or hide ViewBoder and HelpBoder in PropertyGrid.

Answer (score 0):

One rapid and intuitive solution is to create a *Parent Panel* and a *Child Panel* as in the following image:

[image]